# Caml query with unicode charachter

Tags: caml-query, special-characters

the caml query bellow don't return the correct result :

```
<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='ParentLink' /><Value Type='Text'>ⵜⴰⵎⴰⵡⴰⵙⵜ</Value></Eq>  </Where>
```

i think the problem is due to the unicode charchter that i use to search.
there is a solution to escape it ?

Answer (score 4):

You need to surround the data with a CDATA tag:

```
<Value Type="Text"><![CDATA["ⵜⴰⵎⴰⵡⴰⵙⵜ"]]></Value>
```

Comment: Hello thank you for answering,
Unfortunately CDATA tag does'nt resolve my problem. string caml = @"<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='ParentLink' /><Value Type='Text'><![CDATA[ⵜⴰⵎⴰⵡⴰⵙⵜ]]></Value></Eq></Where>"; i note that my text is in Tifinagh. Thanks.

Comment: You have to use quotes too, per the example.

Answer (score 0):

Try encoding the given string before passing it to the CAML query:

```
string EncodeForCAML(string s)  
{           
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();  
    for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; ++i)  
    {  
        char ch = s[i];  
        if (char.IsLetterOrDigit(ch))  
            sb.Append(ch);  
        else 
            sb.AppendFormat("&#{0};", Convert.ToInt32(ch));  
    }  
    return sb.ToString();  
}
```

[SOURCE](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/8b442d22-eb56-40d8-a487-a325d3a70626/caml-query-and-cdata-bug)