# How to retrieve data from unicode character (UTF8) using calmquery?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I try to used calmquery below to retrieve data from sharepoint list column contain unicode character (UTF8) but I still cannot success result.

```
<Where>
  <Contains>
     <FieldRef Name='FullName' />
     <Value Type='Text'>ចាន់ សុភាព</Value>
  </Contains>
```

any advice please share. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `CDATA` tag. Example:

```
<Contains>
     <FieldRef Name='FullName' />
     <Value Type='Text'>![CDATA["ចាន់ សុភាព"]]</Value>
  </Contains>
```

See these for more information:

[How to query using CAML when a value has < in the value](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/11697/how-to-query-using-caml-when-a-value-has-in-the-value)

[Caml query with unicode charachter](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/75573/caml-query-with-unicode-charachter)

Comment: It coming up with all rows that contain Unicode(10/10). actully I have only 1 column that contain  "ចាន់ សុភាព" this value. any advice pls..

Comment: It not working on my environment it used the C# code instead of it. if(item.Title.Contains(strValue)){}